# Error in the log output beamerinnerthemedefault.sty: I can't write on file `"nameofdocument.pdf"'. ...]{beamericonbookshaded}{beamericonbook.20}

Tags: beamer

The code I have been compiling and now when am almost done with the work and about to send there is an error saying *I can't write on file nameofdocument.pdf*. ...]`{beamericonbookshaded}{beamericonbook.20}`.
Now I have installed all the beamer packages that there are and still.

Please advise on what to so other than start a new compilation.
here is the log file:

```
% Copyright 2007 by Till Tantau
% Copyright 2012--2015 by Vedran Mileti\'c, Joseph Wright
% Copyright 2017,2018 by Louis Stuart, Joseph Wright
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/licenses/LICENSE for more details.

\mode<presentation>

% Some images:

\pgfdeclareimage[width=14pt,height=12pt]{beamericonbookshaded}{beamericonbook.20}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericonbook.!20opaque}{beamericonbookshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericonbook.!15opaque}{beamericonbookshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericonbook.!10opaque}{beamericonbookshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericonbook.!5opaque}{beamericonbookshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericonbook.!2opaque}{beamericonbookshaded}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=11pt,height=14pt]{beamericonarticle}{beamericonarticle}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=11pt,height=14pt]{beamericonarticleshaded}{beamericonarticle.20}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericonarticle.!20opaque}{beamericonarticleshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericonarticle.!15opaque}{beamericonarticleshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericonarticle.!10opaque}{beamericonarticleshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericonarticle.!5opaque}{beamericonarticleshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericonarticle.!2opaque}{beamericonarticleshaded}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=14pt,height=14pt]{beamericononline}{beamericononline}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=14pt,height=14pt]{beamericononlineshaded}{beamericononline.20}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericononline.!20opaque}{beamericononlineshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericononline.!15opaque}{beamericononlineshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericononline.!10opaque}{beamericononlineshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericononline.!5opaque}{beamericononlineshaded}
\pgfaliasimage{beamericononline.!2opaque}{beamericononlineshaded}

% Title page: default

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{default}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}


% Part page: default

\defbeamertemplate*{part page}{default}[1][]
{
  \begingroup
    \centering
    {\usebeamerfont{part name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{part name}\partname~\insertromanpartnumber}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=16pt,center,#1]{part title}
      \usebeamerfont{part title}\insertpart\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \endgroup
}


% Section page: default

\defbeamertemplate*{section page}{default}[1][]
{
  \begingroup
    \centering
    {\usebeamerfont{section name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section name}\sectionname~\insertsectionnumber}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center,#1]{section title}
      \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \endgroup
}

% Subection page: default

\defbeamertemplate*{subsection page}{default}[1][]
{
  \begingroup
    \centering
    {\usebeamerfont{subsection name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection name}\subsectionname~\insertsubsectionnumber}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{subsection title}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection title}\insertsubsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \endgroup
}




%
% Table of contents
%

\defbeamertemplateparent{sections/subsections in toc}{section in toc,subsection in toc,subsubsection in toc}
{}

\defbeamertemplateparent{sections/subsections in toc shaded}{section in toc shaded,subsection in toc shaded,subsubsection in toc shaded}[1][20]
{[#1]}




% (sub-)section in toc: default

\defbeamertemplate*{section in toc}{default}
{\inserttocsection\par}

\defbeamertemplate*{subsection in toc}{default}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=1.5em\inserttocsubsection\par}

\defbeamertemplate*{subsubsection in toc}{default}
{\leavevmode\normalsize\usebeamerfont{subsection in toc}\leftskip=3em%
  \usebeamerfont{subsubsection in toc}\inserttocsubsubsection\par}


% (sub-)section in toc shaded, default

\defbeamertemplate*{section in toc shaded}{default}[1][20]
{\begin{colormixin}{#1!parent.bg}\usebeamertemplate{section in toc}\end{colormixin}\unskip}

\defbeamertemplate*{subsection in toc shaded}{default}[1][20]
{\begin{colormixin}{#1!parent.bg}\usebeamertemplate{subsection in toc}\end{colormixin}\unskip}

\defbeamertemplate*{subsubsection in toc shaded}{default}[1][20]
{\begin{colormixin}{#1!parent.bg}\usebeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}\end{colormixin}\unskip}





%
% Item
%

\defbeamertemplateparent{items}{itemize items,enumerate items}
{}


% Itemize items

\defbeamertemplateparent{itemize items}{itemize item,itemize subitem,itemize subsubitem}
{}


% Itemize items, default

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{default}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subitem}{default}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize subitem}\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subsubitem}{default}{\usebeamerfont*{itemize subsubitem}\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}


% Enumerate items, default

\defbeamertemplateparent{enumerate items}{enumerate item,enumerate subitem,enumerate subsubitem,enumerate mini template}
{}

\defbeamertemplate*{enumerate item}{default}{\insertenumlabel.}
\defbeamertemplate*{enumerate subitem}{default}{\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel}
\defbeamertemplate*{enumerate subsubitem}{default}{\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel.\insertsubsubenumlabel}
\defbeamertemplate*{enumerate mini template}{default}{\insertenumlabel}


% Description item, default

\defbeamertemplate*{description item}{default}{\insertdescriptionitem}


% Itemize/Enumerate body

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize/enumerate body begin}{default}{}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize/enumerate body end}{default}{}

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{default}{}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize/enumerate subbody end}{default}{}

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize/enumerate subsubbody begin}{default}{}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize/enumerate subsubbody end}{default}{}

% Description body

\defbeamertemplate*{description body begin}{default}{}
\defbeamertemplate*{description body end}{default}{}


% Alerted text

\defbeamertemplate*{alerted text begin}{default}{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=alerted text}}



% Structured text

% empyt defaults


% Bibliography items

\defbeamertemplate*{bibliography item}{default}
{\lower3.5pt\hbox{\hskip2pt\pgfuseimage{beamericonarticle}\hskip1pt}}

\defbeamertemplate*{bibliography entry article}{default}{}
\defbeamertemplate*{bibliography entry title}{default}{\par}
\defbeamertemplate*{bibliography entry location}{default}{\par}
\defbeamertemplate*{bibliography entry note}{default}{\par}


% Buttons

\newdimen\beamer@dima%
\newdimen\beamer@dimb%

\defbeamertemplate*{button}{default}
{%
  \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{{\insertbuttontext}}%
  \ht\beamer@tempbox=6pt%
  \dp\beamer@tempbox=0pt%
  \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\vbox{\box\beamer@tempbox\vskip2pt}%
  \beamer@tempdim=\wd\beamer@tempbox%
  \beamer@dima=\beamer@tempdim\advance\beamer@dima by2.2pt
  \beamer@dimb=\beamer@tempdim\advance\beamer@dimb by4pt
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-4pt}{0pt}{\the\beamer@tempdim}{8pt}
    \color{bg}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.8pt}
    \pgfpathqmoveto{0pt}{0pt}
    \pgfpathqcurveto{-2.2pt}{0pt}{-4pt}{1.8pt}{-4pt}{4pt}
    \pgfpathqcurveto{-4pt}{6.2pt}{-2.2pt}{8pt}{0pt}{8pt}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@tempdim}{8pt}}
    \pgfpathcurveto%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@dima}{8pt}}%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@dimb}{6.2pt}}%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@dimb}{4pt}}
    \pgfpathcurveto%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@dimb}{1.8pt}}%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@dima}{0pt}}%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@tempdim}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
    \colorlet{bg}{parent.bg}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{button border}
    \pgfpathqmoveto{0pt}{0pt}
    \pgfpathqcurveto{-2.2pt}{0pt}{-4pt}{1.8pt}{-4pt}{4pt}
    \pgfpathqcurveto{-4pt}{6.2pt}{-2.2pt}{8pt}{0pt}{8pt}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@tempdim}{8pt}}
    \pgfpathcurveto%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@dima}{8pt}}%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@dimb}{6.2pt}}%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@dimb}{4pt}}
    \pgfpathcurveto%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@dimb}{1.8pt}}%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@dima}{0pt}}%
    {\pgfpoint{\the\beamer@tempdim}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqstroke
  \end{pgfpicture}%
  \hskip-\beamer@tempdim%
  \box\beamer@tempbox%
  \kern4pt%
}


% Abstract

\defbeamertemplate*{abstract title}{default}
{%
  \begin{center}%
    \abstractname
  \end{center}%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{abstract begin}{default}
{\beamercolorbox[vmode]{abstract}\leftskip2em\rightskip2em plus 1fill\usebeamerfont*{abstract}}

\defbeamertemplate*{abstract end}{default}
{\medskip\endbeamercolorbox}


% Verse

\defbeamertemplate*{verse begin}{default}
{\beamercolorbox[vmode]{verse}}

\defbeamertemplate*{verse end}{default}
{\endbeamercolorbox}


% Quotation

\defbeamertemplate*{quotation begin}{default}
{\beamercolorbox[vmode]{quotation}}

\defbeamertemplate*{quotation end}{default}
{\endbeamercolorbox}


% Quote

\defbeamertemplate*{quote begin}{default}
{\beamercolorbox[vmode]{quote}}

\defbeamertemplate*{quote end}{default}
{\endbeamercolorbox}


% Footnotes

\defbeamertemplate*{footnote}{default}
{
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}


% Captions

\defbeamertemplate*{caption}{default}
{%
  \raggedright
  {%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{caption name}%
    \usebeamerfont*{caption name}%
    \insertcaptionname
    \usebeamertemplate{caption label separator}%
  }%
  \insertcaption\par
}
\defbeamertemplate*{caption label separator}{default}{:\ }

% Blocks

\defbeamertemplateparent{blocks}{block begin,block end,%
  block alerted begin,block alerted end,%
  block example begin,block example end}
{}

\defbeamertemplate*{block begin}{default}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
\defbeamertemplate*{block end}{default}  
{\end{beamercolorbox}\vskip\smallskipamount}

\defbeamertemplate*{block alerted begin}{default}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title alerted}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title alerted}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title alerted}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body alerted}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body alerted}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body alerted}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body alerted}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{block alerted end}{default}
{\end{beamercolorbox}\vskip\smallskipamount}


\defbeamertemplate*{block example begin}{default}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title example}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title example}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title example}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body example}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body example}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body example}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body example}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
\defbeamertemplate*{block example end}{default}
{\end{beamercolorbox}\vskip\smallskipamount}




% Theorems

\defbeamertemplateparent{theorems}{theorem begin,theorem end}
{}

\defbeamertemplate*{theorem begin}{default}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {%
    \inserttheoremname
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
  }%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{theorem end}{default}
{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}


% Proofs
\defbeamertemplate*{proof begin}{default}
{\begin{block}{\insertproofname}}

\defbeamertemplate*{proof end}{default}
{\end{block}}

\defbeamertemplate*{qed symbol}{default}
{\openbox}




\mode
<all>
```

Comment: here is the log file

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That doesn't look like a log file... The `I can't write on file` error says that the location of the output pdf is unaccessible. If you have the pdf file open in the viewer, try closing it. Some viewers (Adobe Reader, for instance) lock the pdf file and that error occurs.

Comment: That is correct. and all the while the file was open. Now that is multi-tasking for you. Thanks plenty. working perfectly

Comment: I started using Windows some time ago and this issue was bugging me too. I'm using SumatraPDF now. It's not all fancy like Adobe Reader but it doesn't lock the pdf file, so you can compile the document with the pdf open.